# Google Play Says Your Device isnt compatible with this application

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I tried all solutions for my problem. 
here is my manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.turk.bakistik"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- xlarge screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.turk.bakistik.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.turk.bakistik.anaekran"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.turk.bakistik.Kayitol"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kayitol"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>     
</application>
</manifest>
```

I uploaded application to google play then started trying on different android phones. 
Some devices found application in search results and some devices could not find.
Lg G2 could not find application. I sended application link then google play said not compatible.

Comment: Not sure but perhaps it may be caused by compatible-screens section, you don't have xxhdpi there. Just try to remove that section completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an (optionnal) list of compatible screens.

Actually, the LG G2 has these properties : 1920 x 1080p so 432 ppp which is a really definition.

In the official documentation ([link to official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)), you can read this :

> Note: This attribute currently does not accept xxhdpi as a valid value, but you can instead specify 480 as the value, which is the approximate threshold for xhdpi screens.

So you could add something like this (adjust it if needed) for LG G2 :

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="480"
    android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```

For the future, be sure that you NEED to limit to certain screen sizes. You are making some limits to your app here : be sure to not forget one screen size.

**Sources & links**

[compatible-screens documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

[Range of screens supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)

Comment: I noticed that LG G2 has no external storage. 
Is it possible because of this? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I don't think so. Try the solution I gave before trying something else ;)

Comment: Ok, i will try both of them because my application does not need external storage. But trying on google play will take hours.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to support all screen sizes?

If that's the case just remove the compatible screens tag and support screens tags altogether. You would only use this if you want to filter certain screens!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.turk.bakistik"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.turk.bakistik.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.turk.bakistik.anaekran"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.turk.bakistik.Kayitol"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kayitol"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>     
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes i want to support all screen sizes. i have different xml files and images for small-large-normal-xlarge in folders. if i remove this tags, will my application reach this folders?

Comment: Yes. And if there is not a folder for a certain configuration, it defaults to the default folder