# Google play deliver application to hdpi and higher

Tags: android, multiscreen

I have submitted my application to google play but it says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

The problem is in the screens limits Ive set. 
It is set as it follows:

```
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen
    android:screenDensity="ldpi"
    android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="mdpi"
    android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="hdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I want to make my application to be supported only by devices with resolution of hdpi and higer but not mdpi and ldpi. Ive made this changes:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

And removed compatible screens tag from manifest but now device with mdpi can download the application that is something that I dont want.

I guess result should be some combination but cant find  the proper way. 
Found something useful in this post : [Google Play Says Your Device isnt compatible with this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275607/google-play-says-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-application) but it wasnt enought to solve my problem. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: "I want to make my application to be supported only by devices with resolution of hdpi and higer but not mdpi and ldpi" -- why? Android will automatically scale your drawable resources for you.

Comment: The application is running fine in all the resolutions I just want to ignore the mentions above because its aimed for large phones only and dont want to support the smaller sizes.

Comment: Density has nothing to do with screen size.